# Словари python, как получить key

Tags: python, list, словари

Как вывести 'Первый' по элементу '221', при этом не создавая еще один словарь

```
d = {
        'Первый': ['205', '221', '325', '924'],
        'Второй': ['608'],
        'Третий': ['169', '805'],
        еще миллиард строк,
        ...,
}
```

Comment: `[key for key, value in d.items() if '221' in value]`

Comment: Получается изначально неудачная модель хранения данных, если приходится по одному элементу из списка из значения искать ключ. А где гарантия что эта '221' уникальна? Только перебором по значениям словаря.

Comment: @andreymal, вы бы print добавили, а то он пропущен, а в вопросе требуется, да в ответ вынесли...

Comment: Стас, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
value='221'
for k, v in d.items():
    if value in v:
       print (k)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {
        'Первый': ['205', '221', '325', '924'],
        'Второй': ['608'],
        'Третий': ['169', '805']
}

num = input("Введите номер элемента: ")
result = [key for key, value in d.items() if num in value]

print(result[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю в зоопарк свою конструкцию с применением генератора и `next()`. Таким образов выведем первый встречающийся ключ, имеющий в списке искомое значение.

```
d = {
        'Первый': ['205', '221', '325', '924'],
        'Второй': ['608'],
        'Третий': ['169', '805']
}

req = '221'
print(next((k for k, v in d.items() if req in v), None))
```